# onPush change detection is always 1 element behind when pushing elements to an array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an upload component where a user can select files.  I am refactoring to `onPush` but I am hitting some weird behaviour:

```
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  files$: BehaviorSubject<FileToUpload[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  readonly files: Observable<FileToUpload[]> = this.files$.asObservable();
  fileStateSubscription: Subscription;
  uploadCandidates$: Subscription;

  activeFiles: FileToUpload[];
  canUpload: boolean;
  isUploading: boolean;

  constructor(
    private uploadService: UploadService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploadService.study$.take(1).subscribe((study) => (this.study = study));
    this.uploadService.currentUser$.take(1).subscribe((currentUser) => (this.currentUser = currentUser));

    this.fileStateSubscription = this.files.subscribe((files) => {
      this.activeFiles = files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success);
      this.canUpload = files.length > 0 && files.every((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.new && f.isValid);
      this.isUploading = files.length > 0 && files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading);
    });
  }

  async upload(event: Event) {
    const fileList: FileList = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

    this.uploadActions.clearUploadCandidates();

    if (!fileList.length) {
      return;
    }

    let files: FileToUpload[];

    files = await this.uploadService.upload(this.files$.getValue(), fileList);

    this.files$.next(this.files$.getValue().concat(files));

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.uploadButtonRef.fileInputRef.nativeElement.value = '';
    });
  }
}
```

The first time I push the template displays `0` even though `fileState.activeFiles` has a length of `1` and the next time I push it displays `1` even though there `fileState.activeFiles` has a length of `2`.

If I remove the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` then everything works as expected.

If change my bring in the `ChangeDetectorRef` and then change my subscription to this:

```
this.fileStateSubscription = this.files$.subscribe((files) => {
  this.activeFiles = files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success);
  this.canUpload = files.length > 0 && files.every((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.new && f.isValid);
  this.isUploading = files.length > 0 && files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading);
  this._changeDetector.markForCheck();
});
```

Then it works but I think that sort of defeats the purpose if I have to explicitly mark every change.

Is it because the code that calls `next` is an `async` function?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you subscribing to `files` or `files$` anywhere else?

Comment: @ggrading no, that is it.  I think it is because the `upload` function that calls `next` is async although I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I have to admit I don't even know why your view is updating. `OnPush` per default deactivates any updating unless explicitely told to do so, e.g. with `markForCheck`. The `async` pipe used in Angular Templates does this "under the hood"

Comment: because the of immutability.  The activeFiles is different each time an item is added.  Angular should pick up new object reference without marking them ever

Comment: I see, you are right about the immutability, but as far as I can see, this only applies if the property is marked with `@Input`. Otherwise, change detection will happen along with any input event, but that's probably too soon if you use observable.

Comment: i’m pretty sure that is not the case with input

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-difference-between-ngdocheck-and-asyncpipe-in-onpush-components-4918ec4b29d4 The author of this blogpost states: "Angular will run change detection for the B component only if its input bindings have changed". As I understand it, all the other properties are not checked for changes.